# Python: access values of a panda series

Tags: python, pandas, series, pandas-groupby

I grouped a dataframe by two columns and calculated a quantile of each group. So the series looks like this now:

```
Group   vehicle
1       car        5.6
        bike      34.0
2       car        7.0
        bike      40.0
```

in a next step I need to check if values are below the quantile and if so, do something. For that, I need to access the specific value (column 3 of the series) for `group` and `vehicle`.

Summed up, how do I get for example the value `34.0` by `group` and `vehicle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select by `tuple` only:

```
val = s.loc[(1, 'bike')]
print (val)
34.0
```

If need select only by first or second level use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
s1 = s.xs(1)
print (s1)
vehicle
car      5.6
bike    34.0
Name: a, dtype: float64

s2 = s.xs('bike', level=1)
print (s2)
Group
1    34.0
2    40.0
Name: a, dtype: float6
```